# index.php# different from index.php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

In my code which is using bootstrap, I got a problem.

I am using JS code shown as below.

```
 $( "li:eq(1)" ).click(function() {
            $.get("./test.php")
               .done(function(data) {
                    $('#middle').html(data);
            });
```

It is to control the div.

```
<div class="container" id=header-nav>
            <a class="brand" href="index.php"></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse" >
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
.......
<div class="container" id="middle"> </div>
```

When I click the test button, the link will change to `test.php#` but nothing change. Click again, it can load into the `test.php`.

The problem is the link is `test.php`, the code not work. when `test.php#` , it work. And I would like to know why.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before using $.get try alert the message. If not working you need to pass correct value to on click event. If its working check your test.php file path.

Comment: Please don't use `alert` for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you have attached the handler to the `li` element, but the `a` element is clicked, and then transfers the page. Try this instead:

```
$("li:eq(1) a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("./test.php")
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#middle').html(data);
        });
});
```

The `preventDefault()` stops the default behaviour of the link, meaning your AJAX request gets executed as required.

Comment: Hi, the issue is still here. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @kelyiu3000 there's no reason that this shouldn't work. Try checking the console for errors (press `F12`)

Answer (score 0):

since you want to use `$.get` (AJAX), you don't have to give the url to `<a>` element inside your `<li>` element,

you have to give the attribute `href` inside `<a>` element this value: `javascript:void(0)` Or `#`,

your `html` code would be:

```
<div class="container" id=header-nav>
            <a class="brand" href="index.php"></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse" >
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
.......
<div class="container" id="middle"> </div>
```

or you have to prevent default action for the element to prevent reloading `url` by adding:
`event.preventDefault()` in you `onclick` event and your `js` code would be:

```
$( "li:eq(1)" ).click(function(e) {
event.preventDefault();
            $.get("./test.php")
               .done(function(data) {
                    $('#middle').html(data);
            });
```